# F-1 student investing in foreign markets

Tags: united-states, stocks, law, f1-student-visa, day-trading

I am currently an F-1 student studying in the US. Before I came to the US, I was day trading stocks back home ('a foreign market') - where I am from.

Can I still day trade from the US in my home country's stock exchange?

Comment: I don't see why not... you're still a citizen of your home country.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have off-campus employment in your first year, but investments are considered passive income no matter how much time you put into that effort.

Obviously you need to stay enrolled full-time and get good enough grades to stay in good standing academically, so you should be cautious about how much time you spend day trading. If the foreign market is also active in a separate time zone, that may help you not to miss class or otherwise divert your attention from your investment in your own education.

I have no idea about your wealth, but it seems to me that completing your degree is more likely to build your wealth than your stock market trades, otherwise you would have stayed home and continued trading instead of attending school in another country.

Comment: Individuals who trade frequently aren't considered investors for US tax purposes and are taxed differently. It's important to keep that in mind when filing.